# CSS position responsive design mobile view

Tags: html, css

I am having issue when it comes to viewing my website in mobile view the text and images are not aligned as they should be they are more off to the left. I have tried using `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)`
It works for the list how ever my container class with everything and footer class doesn't resize as it should.

Desktop design:
http://mah-webbutv.github.io/assets/material/da280a_inl6_bild1.jpg

What I am trying to achieve: 
Mobile design

[image]

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}



.container{

  margin-left:25%;
  padding:1px 16px;
  height:auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    ul {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container{
      margin-left:25%;
      padding:1px 16px;
      height:1000px;
    }

}

div.item {

    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;

    text-align: center;

    width: 520px;
}
.blog {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
.caption {
    display: block;
}

.imgDes {
  margin-left: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}
.imgDes p {
  text-align: right;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>web</title>
<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="htmll logo"></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Länk 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Länk 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Länk 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Länk 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Innehåll</h1>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"  alt="htmll logo" class="blog">
        <span class="caption">
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus

        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="htmll logo" class="blog">
        <span class="caption">

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">

        <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="htmll logo" class="blog">
        <span class="caption">
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
</span>
    </div>
  </div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide-content">
    <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" width="400" height="400" alt="Delicious Ideas from AllRecipes.com">
    <div class="imgDes">

      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
              </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In addition to centering the content for small screens, you will probably want to change how you handle your `<footer>`, since right now it scrolls up in the middle of your content. Do you want the footer to always stay at the bottom of the viewport, visible there regardless of how you scroll? Or do you want it at the bottom of your content, only visible once you reach the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to use `margin: 0 auto` in your media query, which will center the element so that its left and right margins are equal. You'll also want to remove the fixed width from your `.item`, or at least set it to something smaller so that it doesn't overflow your `.container`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}



.container{

  margin-left:25%;
  padding:1px 16px;
  height:auto;
}


div.item {

    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;

    text-align: center;

    width: 520px;
}
.blog {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
.caption {
    display: block;
}

.imgDes {
  margin-left: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}
.imgDes p {
  text-align: right;
}

/* as others have mentioned, you'll need to change this
most likely to position: fixed, unless you want it
just at the bottom of your content, where position: relative
would be OK. Since you haven't asked about it, I've left it
unchanged here */
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}

/* moved your media query to the bottom of your styles,
so it successfully overrides the styles set above */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    ul {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container{
      /* margin: 0 auto; is a great trick for centering */
      margin: 0 auto;
      
      padding:1px 16px;
      height:1000px;
    }
    
    /* remove the set width on your items
    could also set to width: 100%, which would be in line
    with general responsive practices */
    div.item {
      width: initial;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>web</title>
<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="htmll logo"></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Länk 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Länk 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Länk 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Länk 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Innehåll</h1>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png"  alt="htmll logo" class="blog">
        <span class="caption">
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus

        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="htmll logo" class="blog">
        <span class="caption">

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">

        <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" alt="htmll logo" class="blog">
        <span class="caption">
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
</span>
    </div>
  </div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide-content">
    <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png" width="400" height="400" alt="Delicious Ideas from AllRecipes.com">
    <div class="imgDes">

      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
              </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your footer to be always positioned at the bottom of  the page, you should use position: fixed; and not absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

You should be designing mobile first and using @media queries for larger screens.

Now, to your problem... at first glance it looks like you've hardcoded the width of your div.item to 520px wide and you haven't included a rule in the media query to make it 100% wide.